# Delete aux files using glossaries-extra package

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I am using the glossaries-extra package to build my glossary, compiling a pdf with R Markdown. I want to get rid of the aux files (*.acn; *.glo-abr; *.nlo; *.xdy) this package creates in my main work directory.

Comment: If you have access to latexmk just use `latexmk -c mainfile.tex` or even on `*.tex`, if it does not remove all the extensions you mention, you can configure latexmk manually such it knows more extensions to delete. Btw I don't really see the point in removing these files until you're finished with your project.

Comment: I want to put them in other dir, and have my main directory "clean" of those files

Comment: I want to keep them, but in a separate folder...I just don't know how to use the -d option fo makeglossaries

Comment: There are many questions about why does this or that not work when running ./relative sidecar (buggy) files. If your going to move them into another sub folder anyway, It may be much easier to look at this in reverse. Thus build ALL files in a "project" sub folder then just copy? the tex? and pdf? to another master archive folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not with a Makefile?

```
.PHONY: all clean

all:
  pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode --synctex=-1 --shell-escape main.tex

clean:
  --@rm -rf *-gnuplottex-fig*.* *.gnuploterrors
  --@rm -rf *.aux *.log *.lof *.bak *.loa *.log *.lot *.bbl *.blg *.dvi *.out *.brf
  --@rm -rf *.thm *.toc *.idx *.ilg *.ind *eps-converted-to.pdf *.gnuplot *.tps
  --@rm -rf *-gnuplottex-fig*.* *temp*.dat *.nav *.snm *.vrb *.lol *.tmp
  --@rm -rf gnuplottex *.synctex *.synctex.gz *.xwm
```

just run `make` and you have your PDF, and `make clean` lets you tidy up your working directory. Further, if you have a subfolder, for example with standalone TikZ drawings or plots, you can recurse the subdirectories with the following Makefile:

```
SUBDIRS := $(sort $(dir $(wildcard tikz/*/*)))

.PHONY: all $(SUBDIRS) clean

all: $(SUBDIRS)
  pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode --synctex=-1 --shell-escape main.tex

$(SUBDIRS):  ; $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

clean: $(SUBDIRS)
  --@rm -rf *-gnuplottex-fig*.* *.gnuploterrors
  --@rm -rf *.aux *.log *.lof *.bak *.loa *.log *.lot *.bbl *.blg *.dvi *.out *.brf
  --@rm -rf *.thm *.toc *.idx *.ilg *.ind *eps-converted-to.pdf *.gnuplot *.tps
  --@rm -rf *-gnuplottex-fig*.* *temp*.dat *.nav *.snm *.vrb *.lol *.tmp
  --@rm -rf gnuplottex *.synctex *.synctex.gz *.xwm
```

This first goes into each subfolder in the tikz/ folder, executes the Makefile found in that folder, and then goes back to the main folder and builds the main document. When cleaning up, the subdirectories are cleaned as well, of course.